# AquilineTwo Font

Tags: fonts, line-spacing, calligraphy

[This is how I would want AquilineTwo to look like when I type.](http://www.brighthub.com/multimedia/publishing/articles/80532.aspx#imgn_11)

But that is not the case when I downloaded AquilineTwo from anywhere. (specifically from UrbanFonts.com)

Where can I download the ones from the picture, or what am I suppose to do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I'm afraid this question seems to be off-topic for this site. Is it related to TeX/LaTeX in any way?

Answer (score 2):

With `pdflatex` can use one of the usual calligraphic fonts of [The LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html), like Zapt Chancery:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chancery}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\Large
\section*{\Huge Lore Lipsum}
\raggedright
 \itshape \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

As alternative, you can use `XeTeX` or `LuaTeX` with any true type font available in your OS. For demonstration purposes, the MWE use the Anaktoria font, although is not similar to the font of the question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Anaktoria}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\Large
\section*{\Huge Lore Lipsum}
\raggedright
 \itshape \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE2]